# Error Code 13 Msg: Directory dosen't exist...when starting Gazebo with .world file including .sdf-models

Tags: gazebo, ros2, sdf, world, gazebo-world

i have trouble running a world with Gazebo (Version 11.10.2)...

When i run the world with the command:`gazebo test.world`  i receive the error:

```
Error Code 13 Msg: Directory doesn't exist[/home/henrik/gazebo_models/box.sdf]
```

in my test.world file i tried to import the simple model box.sdf.
The file is correctly added to the default file path `/home/henrik/gazebo_models/` which i have checked with the command `echo $GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH`.
When i delete the box.sdf file from the folder i receive the error

```
Error Code 12 Msg: Unable to find uri[model://box.sdf]
```

So i'm sure that the path for the file are correctly declared in my code...
Here is my code for the test.world file (default world with an include-tag):

```
<world name='default'>
 <light name='sun' type='directional'>
   <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
   <pose>0 0 10 0 -0 0</pose>
   <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
   <specular>0.2 0.2 0.2 1</specular>
   <attenuation>
     <range>1000</range>
     <constant>0.9</constant>
     <linear>0.01</linear>
     <quadratic>0.001</quadratic>
   </attenuation>
   <direction>-0.5 0.1 -0.9</direction>
   <spot>
     <inner_angle>0</inner_angle>
     <outer_angle>0</outer_angle>
     <falloff>0</falloff>
   </spot>
 </light>
 <model name='ground_plane'>
   <static>1</static>
   <link name='link'>
     <collision name='collision'>
       <geometry>
         <plane>
           <normal>0 0 1</normal>
           <size>100 100</size>
         </plane>
       </geometry>
       <surface>
         <friction>
           <ode>
             <mu>100</mu>
             <mu2>50</mu2>
           </ode>
           <torsional>
             <ode/>
           </torsional>
         </friction>
         <contact>
           <ode/>
         </contact>
         <bounce/>
       </surface>
       <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
     </collision>
     <visual name='visual'>
       <cast_shadows>0</cast_shadows>
       <geometry>
         <plane>
           <normal>0 0 1</normal>
           <size>100 100</size>
         </plane>
       </geometry>
       <material>
         <script>
           <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
           <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
         </script>
       </material>
     </visual>
     <self_collide>0</self_collide>
     <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
     <kinematic>0</kinematic>
   </link>
 </model>
 <gravity>0 0 -9.8</gravity>
 <magnetic_field>6e-06 2.3e-05 -4.2e-05</magnetic_field>
 <atmosphere type='adiabatic'/>
 <physics type='ode'>
   <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
   <real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor>
   <real_time_update_rate>1000</real_time_update_rate>
 </physics>
 <scene>
   <ambient>0.4 0.4 0.4 1</ambient>
   <background>0.7 0.7 0.7 1</background>
   <shadows>1</shadows>
 </scene>
 <audio>
   <device>default</device>
 </audio>
 <wind/>
 <spherical_coordinates>
   <surface_model>EARTH_WGS84</surface_model>
   <latitude_deg>0</latitude_deg>
   <longitude_deg>0</longitude_deg>
   <elevation>0</elevation>
   <heading_deg>0</heading_deg>
 </spherical_coordinates>
 <state world_name='default'>
   <sim_time>67 88000000</sim_time>
   <real_time>33 922535300</real_time>
   <wall_time>1707378083 703017874</wall_time>
   <iterations>33744</iterations>
   <model name='ground_plane'>
     <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
     <scale>1 1 1</scale>
     <link name='link'>
       <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
       <velocity>0 0 0 0 -0 0</velocity>
       <acceleration>0 0 0 0 -0 0</acceleration>
       <wrench>0 0 0 0 -0 0</wrench>
     </link>
   </model>
   <model name='unit_box'>
     <pose>-0.843152 -0.012954 0.5 0 -0 0</pose>
     <scale>1 1 1</scale>
     <link name='link'>
       <pose>-0.843152 -0.012954 0.5 0 -0 0</pose>
       <velocity>0 0 0 0 -0 0</velocity>
       <acceleration>-0.004709 -9.78112 9.78158 0.712677 -0.009414 -4.3e-05</acceleration>
       <wrench>-0.004709 -9.78112 9.78158 0 -0 0</wrench>
     </link>
   </model>
   <light name='sun'>
     <pose>0 0 10 0 -0 0</pose>
   </light>
 </state>
 <gui fullscreen='0'>
   <camera name='user_camera'>
     <pose>5 -5 2 0 0.275643 2.35619</pose>
     <view_controller>orbit</view_controller>
     <projection_type>perspective</projection_type>
   </camera>
 </gui>
 <include>
   <uri>model://box.sdf</uri>
   <name>aaa</name>
 </include>    
</world>
</sdf>

 enter<sdf version='1.7'>
<world name='default'>
 <light name='sun' type='directional'>
   <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
   <pose>0 0 10 0 -0 0</pose>
   <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
   <specular>0.2 0.2 0.2 1</specular>
   <attenuation>
     <range>1000</range>
     <constant>0.9</constant>
     <linear>0.01</linear>
     <quadratic>0.001</quadratic>
   </attenuation>
   <direction>-0.5 0.1 -0.9</direction>
   <spot>
     <inner_angle>0</inner_angle>
     <outer_angle>0</outer_angle>
     <falloff>0</falloff>
   </spot>
 </light>
 <model name='ground_plane'>
   <static>1</static>
   <link name='link'>
     <collision name='collision'>
       <geometry>
         <plane>
           <normal>0 0 1</normal>
           <size>100 100</size>
         </plane>
       </geometry>
       <surface>
         <friction>
           <ode>
             <mu>100</mu>
             <mu2>50</mu2>
           </ode>
           <torsional>
             <ode/>
           </torsional>
         </friction>
         <contact>
           <ode/>
         </contact>
         <bounce/>
       </surface>
       <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
     </collision>
     <visual name='visual'>
       <cast_shadows>0</cast_shadows>
       <geometry>
         <plane>
           <normal>0 0 1</normal>
           <size>100 100</size>
         </plane>
       </geometry>
       <material>
         <script>
           <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
           <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
         </script>
       </material>
     </visual>
     <self_collide>0</self_collide>
     <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
     <kinematic>0</kinematic>
   </link>
 </model>
 <gravity>0 0 -9.8</gravity>
 <magnetic_field>6e-06 2.3e-05 -4.2e-05</magnetic_field>
 <atmosphere type='adiabatic'/>
 <physics type='ode'>
   <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
   <real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor>
   <real_time_update_rate>1000</real_time_update_rate>
 </physics>
 <scene>
   <ambient>0.4 0.4 0.4 1</ambient>
   <background>0.7 0.7 0.7 1</background>
   <shadows>1</shadows>
 </scene>
 <audio>
   <device>default</device>
 </audio>
 <wind/>
 <spherical_coordinates>
   <surface_model>EARTH_WGS84</surface_model>
   <latitude_deg>0</latitude_deg>
   <longitude_deg>0</longitude_deg>
   <elevation>0</elevation>
   <heading_deg>0</heading_deg>
 </spherical_coordinates>
 <state world_name='default'>
   <sim_time>67 88000000</sim_time>
   <real_time>33 922535300</real_time>
   <wall_time>1707378083 703017874</wall_time>
   <iterations>33744</iterations>
   <model name='ground_plane'>
     <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
     <scale>1 1 1</scale>
     <link name='link'>
       <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
       <velocity>0 0 0 0 -0 0</velocity>
       <acceleration>0 0 0 0 -0 0</acceleration>
       <wrench>0 0 0 0 -0 0</wrench>
     </link>
   </model>
   <model name='unit_box'>
     <pose>-0.843152 -0.012954 0.5 0 -0 0</pose>
     <scale>1 1 1</scale>
     <link name='link'>
       <pose>-0.843152 -0.012954 0.5 0 -0 0</pose>
       <velocity>0 0 0 0 -0 0</velocity>
       <acceleration>-0.004709 -9.78112 9.78158 0.712677 -0.009414 -4.3e-05</acceleration>
       <wrench>-0.004709 -9.78112 9.78158 0 -0 0</wrench>
     </link>
   </model>
   <light name='sun'>
     <pose>0 0 10 0 -0 0</pose>
   </light>
 </state>
 <gui fullscreen='0'>
   <camera name='user_camera'>
     <pose>5 -5 2 0 0.275643 2.35619</pose>
     <view_controller>orbit</view_controller>
     <projection_type>perspective</projection_type>
   </camera>
 </gui>
 <include>
   <uri>model://box.sdf</uri>
   <name>aaa</name>
 </include>    
</world>
</sdf>
```

And here is the code for the box.sdf-file (from https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=build_model&cat=build_robot):

````
<sdf version="1.4">
  <model name="my_model">
    <pose>0 0 0.5 0 0 0</pose>
    <static>true</static>
    <link name="link">
      <inertial>
        <mass>1.0</mass>
        <inertia> <!-- inertias are tricky to compute -->
          <!-- http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=inertia&cat=build_robot -->
          <ixx>0.083</ixx>       <!-- for a box: ixx = 0.083 * mass * (y*y + z*z) -->
          <ixy>0.0</ixy>         <!-- for a box: ixy = 0 -->
          <ixz>0.0</ixz>         <!-- for a box: ixz = 0 -->
          <iyy>0.083</iyy>       <!-- for a box: iyy = 0.083 * mass * (x*x + z*z) -->
          <iyz>0.0</iyz>         <!-- for a box: iyz = 0 -->
          <izz>0.083</izz>       <!-- for a box: izz = 0.083 * mass * (x*x + y*y) -->
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
      <collision name="collision">
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>1 1 1</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <visual name="visual">
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>1 1 1</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>```
````